# Spring JPA specification with enum mapping

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, specifications

In my project, I used a complicated enum for my entity, and I want to do some search function with specification using JPA.

(Entity)
CoDocument.java

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name ="co_document")
public class CoDocument {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false , name = "co_application_type")
  private CoApplicationType coApplicationType; //DB column is CHAR(255)


}
```

(Specification)
RepositorySpecification.java

```
public class RepositorySpecification implements Specification<CoDocument> {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7694054498602732930L;
    private final List<SearchCriteria> list;

    public CoapRepositorySpecification(List<SearchCriteria> list) {
        this.list = list != null ? list : new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<CoDocument> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        List<Predicate> andPredicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SearchCriteria criteria : list) {
            if (criteria.getValue() == null || !StringUtils.hasLength(criteria.getValue().toString())) {
                continue;
            }

            Path<String> rootKey = root.get(criteria.getKey();

            andPredicates.add(builder.like(
                     rootKey,
                     "%" + criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }
        return builder.and(andPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
```

(Enum)
CoApplicationType.java

```
@Getter @Setter
public enum CoApplicationType {
    CO_TYPE_A("CO(Maldives)","CO_MALDIVES"),
    CO_TYPE_B("CO(ASE)","CO_ASE");

    private String applicationType;
    private String formName;

    private CoApplicationType(String appicationType, String formName){
        this.applicationType = appicationType;
        this.formName = formName;
    }
```

(Enum converter)
CoApplicationTypeConverter.java

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class CoApplicationTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<CoApplicationType, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(CoApplicationType coApplicationType) {
        if (coApplicationType == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return coApplicationType.getAppicationType();
    }

    @Override
    public CoApplicationType convertToEntityAttribute(String applicationType) {
        if (applicationType == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return Stream.of(CoApplicationType.values())
                .filter(c -> c.getAppicationType().equals(applicationType))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

But here comes the exception:
`Parameter value [%ASE%] did not match expected type [com.scm.co.constant.CoApplicationType (n/a)]`
There's something wrong with the type in the entity, and I have no clue searching the document online.

What I want to do in SQL statement is like:
`SELECT * FROM co_document WHERE coApplicationType like "%ASE%";`
and it does work in MySQL Workbench.

But I'm not sure how to convert it into JPA with specification, and with complicated enum structure.

Any reply would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `Expression<String> rootKey = ((ExpressionImplementor)root.get(criteria.getKey()).asString();` instead of `Path<String> rootKey = root.get(criteria.getKey();`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Unfortunately , it gives me the same exception:
`Parameter value [%ASE%] did not match expected type [com.scm.co.constant.CoApplicationType (n/a)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add

```java
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) // dataType of your enum
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false , name = "co_application_type")
private CoApplicationType coApplicationType; //DB column is CHAR(255);
```

for enums you have to add `@Enumerated` annotation before your column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it is for simple Enum type case. Take a look on https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa , my case is similar to the `Category`, and it needs no `@Enumerated` annotation, but a enum converter instead. 

In your case, hibernate throws another exception:  `No enum constant com.scm.co.constant.CoApplicationType.CO(ASE)` when extracting data from DB.

Comment: For that particular value you don't have to go for db call in controller you can add logic     
/*if (strRoles == null) {
   Authority userRole = roleRepository.findRoleByName(ERole.ROLE_PROFFESOR)
     .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(MessageConstants.ROLE_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE));
   roles.add(userRole);
  } else {
   strRoles.forEach(role -> {
    switch (role) { case "admin": Authority adminRole = roleRepository.findRoleByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(MessageConstants.ROLE_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE));
      roles.add(adminRole);
      break;